# 'Find-AzureRmResource' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cloud, devops, azure-powershell

I am trying to nuke an azure subscription and I found this

https://www.frankysnotes.com/2016/12/need-to-nuke-azure-subscription.html

As I run the final part I got an error of

> "Find-AzureRmResource : The term 'Find-AzureRmResource' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
> file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
> and try again."

Can someone help me how to fix this so I can nuke my Azure subscription?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `AzureRM` module, use `Az` module as the former is now deprecated. To learn more about it, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-7.5.0.

Simplest code to delete all resources from a subscription would be to list resource groups in that subscription and then delete them.

Your code would be something like:

```
Get-AzResourceGroup | Remove-AzResourceGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Get-AzureRmResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.13.0) instead of *Find-AzureRmResource*.
*Find-AzureRmResource* is depreacted.

> Starting with version 6.0 of Azure PowerShell, Find-AzureRmResource have been removed and Get-AzureRmResource is supposed to be the workaround.

[How to safely replace Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType calls in Azure PowerShell 6.x+](https://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-safely-replace-find-azurermresource-resourcetype-calls-in-azure-powershell-6-x/)